# Motion of car on banked road

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

The formula for the maximum speed on a banked road is given as:

$$ v_\textrm{max} = \sqrt{\frac{Rg(\mu_s + \tan\theta)}{1 - \mu_s\tan\theta}} $$

Where $\mu$ represents the coefficient of friction on the road, and $\theta$ is the angle of inclination of the plane. What would happen to the maximum speed if $\mu\tan\theta$ was greater than or equal to $1$?

Comment: Where did you get the equation? Units are wrong ($v=m^{2}/s^2$). For proper equation see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/carbank.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually when this kind of thing happens, an assumption has turned out to be wrong. There are two ways to approach it. The first is to check the derivation carefully, the other is to consider limiting cases. The first is more time-consuming, while the second might not always be possible.

In this case we are fortunate that the second approach is doable. Consider $\mu_s \rightarrow \infty$ (in other words, infinite friction). In that case the car is never going to slip, even if the banking angle is very small. But if the car never slips, then there is no $V_{max}$.

Therein lies the answer: if $1 - \mu_s \tan(\theta) < 0$, then there is no $V_{max}$. It doesn't matter what speed you drive at, you are still not slipping.